# How to load multiple xml files?

Tags: javascript

I want to load different XML files on buttons click. How can I send it to the function?

```
<button onclick = 'loadXMLDoc(a.xml)'></button>
<button onclick = 'loadXMLDoc(b.xml)'><button>
<script>
    function loadXMLDoc(a) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                myFunction(this);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "a", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript calling needs to pass a string, also the second `<button>` is not closed, have a look at:

```html
<button onclick = "loadXMLDoc('a.xml')"></button>
<button onclick = "loadXMLDoc('b.xml')"></button>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc(a) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myFunction(this);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", a, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```